# App was denied on playstore because of violation of section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Tags: android, html, webview, youtube

I have just received following email:

> > This is a notification that your application submission, Chami Browser, for package ID com.chami.browser, has been rejected. If this
> >     submission was an update to an existing app, the version published
> >     prior to this update is still available on Google Play.
>
> Please address the issue described below, then submit an update with
>   your changes.
>
> REASON FOR REJECTION:Violation of section 4.4 of the Developer
>   Distribution Agreement.
>
> After a regular review, we have determined that your app downloads,
>   monetizes, or otherwise accesses YouTube videos in violation of the
>   YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service. Accessing
>   content, a product, or service in an unauthorized manner is a
>   violation of the Developer Distribution Agreement, and is not allowed
>   on Google Play.
>
> All submission rejections are tracked. Repeated rejections due to
>   policy violations will result in app suspension, at which point this
>   app will count as a strike against the good standing of your developer
>   account and no longer be available on Google Play.
>
> This notification also serves as notice for other apps in your
>   catalog. You can avoid future submission rejections and/or app
>   suspensions by immediately ensuring that no other apps in your catalog
>   are in violation of (but not limited to) the above policy. Before
>   publishing applications, please ensure your apps’ compliance with the
>   Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit
>   this Google Play Help Center article.
>
> The Google Play Team

They provided me one more aditional information in developer console. they think that i am violating terms and conditions of Youtube or Youtube API.
I dont really understand this. My app doesnt use Youtube API. My app allows to view HTML5 videos in webview and show them on fullscreen. This is achieved by following implementation of WebChromeClient.

```
 class mojWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private View nacitavanieVideaView;
        private FrameLayout vlastnyViewFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FLvideo);

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

            if (mojVlastnyView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mojVlastnyView = view;
            net.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.PBnacitavanie).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.RLOvladaciPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vlastnyViewFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vlastnyViewFrameLayout.addView(view);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            vlastnyViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {


            if (nacitavanieVideaView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HlavnaAktivita.this);
                nacitavanieVideaView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nacitavanie_videa, null);
            }
            return nacitavanieVideaView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();
            if (mojVlastnyView == null)
                return;

            net.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.PBnacitavanie).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.RLOvladaciPanel).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vlastnyViewFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mojVlastnyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            vlastnyViewFrameLayout.removeView(mojVlastnyView);
            vlastnyViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                mojVlastnyView = null;
            }
}
```

And then i simply applied WebChromeClient on Webview in onCreate():

```
 WebView net = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.net);
net.setWebChromeClient(new mojWebChromeClient());
```

Comment: If they say you are violating A or B, and you are not using B, then look at A.

Comment: In my opinion my app isnt violating nor A nor B, i am really confuesed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the launch of Youtube API it's preffered you use the sdk . It's simply better. Videos served in youtube via webview show ads and you are not in control of those ads . Simply use youtube sdk for android

Also , read TOS on youtube.com